# How to get the parameters using scipy.stats.gamma.fit method <-- wiht data of 2 by 2 matrix

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, distribution

Could you let me know the way to obtain the parameters of gamma distribution by gamma.fit(). In case of 1-d array vector data (exampe, size = 100 when creating random values), the parameters are easily computed, but there are errors when 2d-array of 100 x 100 has been input as following.

```
a = 5
loc = 100.5
b = 22
data = gamma.rvs(a, loc = loc, scale = b, size = (100,100)) 
res = gamma.fit(data)
```

ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()ValueError:

Comment: Most likely, you can only fit a one-dimensional array.

Comment: `res = gamma.fit(data.ravel())`